# What is the option I should use for basicstyle in \lstset if I want Times New Roman font in source code?

Tags: fonts, listings, sourcecode

I copied the following from somewhere in Internet to the beginning of the latex document to enable math escape in source code listing :

```
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  mathescape
}
```

As expected, the output is using equal-width characters like this:
[image]

I don't like this font in source code, so is there any option to change the font of source code to something like Times New Roman (regular font used in common textbook). Or, if there is a documentation in Internet that lists all the available options for `basicstyle` in `\lstset`, please let me know the link so that I can choose what I want (I did not find it in Google). Thanks.

Comment: maybe `\rmfamily` would be acceptable? `rm` stands for 'Roman', not necessarily Times New Roman, but it might use Times if that is in use elsewhere in your document.

Comment: @Marijn: Thank you so much. Yes, `\rmfamily` provides the font I want. A small glitch: it does not work very well with math in source code. For example `X-1` has to wrap -1 with dollar signs. But it is not a big issue for me because my code is not very long. Do you mind escalate your comment to an answer? Thanks.

Comment: Actually the example that you give looks more like pseudocode instead of actual executable source code (if it is actual code then I don't recognize the language). So maybe one of the pseudocode packages might be more useful here, instead of `listings`? See for an overview https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms. Such packages usually have good font defaults to accomodate short sentences, math etc.

Comment: @Marijn: Yes, you are right. The program is not actual executable source code; it's a language used in a TCS text to develop theory of computability, complexity, formal language and automata, so it's more like pseudocodes in algorithms in which $\leftarrow$ is used for assignment and subscripts are used to represent different variables. I'll take a look at the pseudocode packages you mentioned.